# Incorrect encoding exception when connecting to FCM using Smack Library

Tags: android, smack, firebase-cloud-messaging, sasl

I am trying to connect to FCM using the smack library:

Here's what I've tried. It works, but I get an exception when the connection tries to login.

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder configBuilder =     XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();
private Handler umm;
@Override
public void run() {
                        configBuilder.setSecurityMode(XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled );
configBuilder.setServiceName("fcm-xmpp.googleapis.com");
configBuilder.setHost("fcm-xmpp.googleapis.com");//MAYBE PROBLEM HERE??
configBuilder.setPort(5236);
configBuilder.setCompressionEnabled(false);
configBuilder.setSendPresence(true);
                         configBuilder.setSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory.getDefault());
InterfaceClass.FCMconnection = new XMPPTCPConnection(configBuilder.build());
umm = yes;

try {
InterfaceClass.FCMconnection.connect();
Log.v("pony", "white horse");
//InterfaceClass.FCMloggin.start();
android.os.Message y4 = android.os.Message.obtain();
y4.what = LOGINTOFCM;
umm.sendMessage(y4);
//the rest of the thread is just exception handling in catch clauses
```

Once my handler receives the message I attempt to login with the connection
like this:

```
try {                        FCMconnection.login("senderId@gcm.googleapis.com","SERVER_KEY");
Log.d("black","r2d2");
} catch (XMPPException e) {//exception thrown here
e.printStackTrace();
Log.d("black","maity "+e);
```

I get the following excecption: 
    "smack.sasl.SASLErrorException: SASLError using X-OAUTH2: incorrect-    encoding"

Now from the documentation it says clearly to implement SASL plain mechanism, 
but I don't know how? Here's what the documentation says:

"The connection has two important requirements:

You must initiate a Transport Layer Security (TLS) connection. Note that CCS doesn't currently support the STARTTLS extension.
***CCS requires a SASL PLAIN authentication mechanism using*** @gcm.googleapis.com (FCM sender ID) and the Server key as the password, where the sender ID and Server key are the values you gathered when configuring your client app. See the client documentation for your platform for information on obtaining these credentials."

Does anybody have any idea what could be causing this exception? How should I connect to FCM with the smack library?

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation connecting to FCM over XMPP protocol needs:

1) TLS connection in transport layer, to achieve this create SSLContext using TLS protocol extension

2) Plain SASL protocol, make sure "smack-sasl-javax-4.1.8.jar" is integrated into your build setup. This took me lot of time to figure out

3) Host, service name and port number are correct(refer code snippet below)

Below code snippet works perfectly for me:

```
SSLContext sslContext = null;
try {
    sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslContext.init(null, null, null);
} catch (Exception e) {
    //Failed to get default ssl context with TLS enabled... something can't proceed further
}
XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();
config.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
config.setSendPresence(true);
config.setCustomSSLContext(sslContext);
config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);
config.setServiceName("gcm.googleapis.com");
config.setHost("fcm-xmpp.googleapis.com");
config.setPort(5236);//not production server
config.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
config.setCompressionEnabled(true);
config.setSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
(mConnection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config.build())).addConnectionListener(ConnectionSession.this);
mConnection.setPacketReplyTimeout(REPLY_TIMEOUT);
mConnection.connect();
mConnection.login(userID, password); //use your app server credential here
```

Smack version 4.8.1 implemented and tested from openfire setup.

Hope this help someone!!